# How to assign a boost::tuple to boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, boost-tuples

In my code I have something like this

```
shrd_ptr_obj st = boost::make_shared<Myobj>();
Myobj tp =  boost::make_tuple(0,0,0,0,0 );
```

How do I make st point to tp ?

Comment: Is `Myobj` a typedef for `tuple<something>`?

Comment: yes its `boost::tuple<double,double, double,double,double>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural way is to pass the constructor parameter(s) to `make_shared` and create the object on the same line.

```
shrd_ptr_obj st = boost::make_shared<Myobj>(boost::make_tuple(0,0,0,0,0));
```

If you want to construct the object in a separate step, you'll need to allocate `tp` with `new` rather than creating it on the stack. Then you can create a `boost::shared_ptr` from this `new`ed pointer.

```
Myobj *tp = new Myobj(boost::make_tuple(0,0,0,0,0));
shrd_ptr_obj st = boost::shared_ptr<Myobj>(tp);
```

Comment: I think the last line was suppose to be `boost::make_shared<Myobj>(tp)`